# PHP function to update PHP variables not being called in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

It's probably super-simple, but I want to update the PHP variables by getting a new random record from the SQL server, and then pass those variables into JavaScript to use them, however the PHP function I've called only works once and then stops working. I don't know if something is wrong with the function call or with the function itself.

```
<?php

function getQuestion(){
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "pass", "projectDB");
    $sql = "SELECT question, answerA, answerB, answerC, answerD, 
    correctAns FROM questionTable ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 3";

    global $result, $row, $question, $answerA, $answerB, $answerC, 
    $answerD, $correctAns;

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $question = $row["question"];
    $answerA = $row["answerA"];
    $answerB = $row["answerB"];
    $answerC = $row["answerC"];
    $answerD = $row["answerD"];
    $correctAns = $row["correctAns"];

    mysqli_close($conn);
}

getQuestion();

?>
<script>
    var answerA = "<?php echo $answerA; ?>";
    var answerB = "<?php echo $answerB; ?>";
    var answerC = "<?php echo $answerC; ?>";
    var answerD = "<?php echo $answerD; ?>";
    var question = "<?php echo $question; ?>";
    var correctAnswer = "<?php echo $correctAns; ?>";

    function newQuestion(){

        <?php getQuestion(); ?>

        question = "<?php echo $question; ?>";
        answerA = "<?php echo $answerA; ?>";
        answerB = "<?php echo $answerB; ?>";
        answerC = "<?php echo $answerC; ?>";
        answerD = "<?php echo $answerD; ?>";
        correctAnswer = "<?php echo $correctAns; ?>";
    }

    else if (targetHit == true){ 
    reset(); 
    newQuestion();
    tick = 0;
    }
</script>
```

The first time the variables are defined and getQuestion() is used in the top PHP, they get correct values, and the first time newQuestion() is called they get updated with different correct values, however after that, calling newQuestion() does not change any of the values like it should.
Thanks.

Comment: There is no way to directly call PHP functions from JS. PHP is executed on the server before page loads, js runs afterward on the client.

Comment: What you want is AJAX [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started).

Answer (score 0):

Its not a correct way to write php code in javascript even we should not write php code in javascript. better to retrieve value from database and store value on javascript variable by ajax request. its give you sql result every time.
make a php file to retrieve data and another php or js file to ajax request.
here a code for

php files as wrote

```
function getQuestion(){
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "pass", "projectDB");
$sql = "SELECT question, answerA, answerB, answerC, answerD, 
correctAns FROM questionTable ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 3";

global $result, $row, $question, $answerA, $answerB, $answerC, 
$answerD, $correctAns;

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$question = $row["question"];
$answerA = $row["answerA"];
$answerB = $row["answerB"];
$answerC = $row["answerC"];
$answerD = $row["answerD"];
$correctAns = $row["correctAns"];
mysqli_close($conn);
return $correctAns;}
echo json_encode(getQuestion());
```

here ajax request to get result

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'phpfilename.php',
        success: function ( data ) {
          alert(JSON.parse(data));
        },
         error:function(error){
             console.log(error);
           }
      });
```